# (When) are questions about salary level (job J, country C) on topic?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Prompted by this question: [Average Salary for C# , K2 Developer in US, Canada , Germany](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14637/average-salary-for-c-k2-developer-in-us-canada-germany)

This one sounds both too broad (several countries) and too specific (what is *K2 Denallix*?). The last reason makes the question uninteresting for others.

Since I found no [questions on 'salary' on meta](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=salary):

**What guidelines do we use for salary level questions?**

Answer (score 1):

Simply asking about average salaries around multiple countries is off topic here for multiple reasons. One is that they are very much "shopping-style" questions, which is off-topic on most SE site, and on the other hand as stated they are not really expat related.

I went through some salary related questions we already have, and I have the following assumptions:

- Asking if a specific salary is enough or not is borderline okay. It can be argued that someone who is new in a country will not know what costs they could expect as net salaries and cost-of-living can vary widely between countries, so it's related to expats. It can also be helpful to other visitors so it's not too specific.
- Asking about comparisons between countries could also be borderline okay. E.g. questions like "I am currently earning $X, but I will earn £Y afterwards, is it going to be better or not". These questions are similar to above.
- Questions related to taxes on salaries, especially if there are different tax regimes for expats are okay - but we also accept questions asking about how taxation works in a country.
- Questions about taxations across multiple countries, e.g. where you have to pay taxes is still relevant to expats and therefore is on topic.

Also I usually give a small leeway before closing questions as off-topic as [sometimes there are circumstances that become clear during an answer](https://expatriates.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341/what-is-our-stance-on-questions-about-moving-to-a-different-part-of-the-same-cou/343#343). However the question mentioned doesn't generally fit into SE's format as well so there's no point in having it around.